# How can i force a Custom UI to close when blender is already closed?

Tags: python, interface

I'm a newbie Blender ^^"

I've some issues with a custom UI/widget. When I close Blender, my custom widget freeze and stay open (but blender is closed !). I can't close it. When I force the close, this Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBE94C50D5 (python39.dll) in blender.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000000000000009.

Does someone know how I can close my widget?
I use Python.

Thx

Comment: Not sure exactly what your widget is but you can user `atexit.register` to add a callback to close your widget. It will be called just before blender closes. https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html

Comment: thanks. I will try it.
My widget is a window with 4 buttons (load/publish/import/create entity).